# Hibernate HQL query - complicated

Tags: hibernate

I need to write some HQL to do the following...

I have 3 tables: club, team and game (column names below)

=School=
-id(pk)
-name

=Team= 
-id(pk)
-name
-club_id(fk)

=Game=
-id(pk)
-opposition
-homeScore
-awayScore
-team_id(fk)

I need to select the last 20 games played for a specified club...

something like: "select last 20 games from all teams that belong to club X"

Does anyone know how i could do this in HQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Should be easier with ICriteria than with HQL. Had something similar. Hacked it together w/o deeper knowledge - can't help much. :)

Comment: Table structure does not matter that much when you're dealing with HQL. Can you post your mappings instead? Is team-games relationship bi-directional? Same for school-team?

Answer (score 0):

it goes something like (untested):

```
select g from teams t join t.games g where t.club = :club
     order by g.date
```

In order to restrict the result to the first 20

```
session.createQuery(theQuery)
     .setEntity('club',club)
     .setMaxResults(20)
     .list();
```

Trouble with HQL is that it is really had to write it with out actually being able to run the stuff.